# Category Save Error after upgrading from 2.07 to 2.1

Tags: php, magento

In 2.07 I can go to products, categories, and add products to categories, remove products etc. From the product, I can see what categories the product is in and make changes.

The upgrade to 2.1 went flawlessly. No errors

I can see the categories in admin and see product in a category - but if I try to remove a product (uncheck) and save it gives me the error:

> Something went wrong while saving the category.

If I go to products and edit a product in the category box I see nothing. If I try to search for a category it does nothing.

I looked through several traces and see one that might have a hint:

> Undefined index: optgroup while running vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/Component/Product/Form/Categories/Options.php

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?, I am facing the same issue.